# Creating new text files with names from an array in Python

Tags: python, list, file-io

I'm fairly rusty in Python (and my skills, when not rusty, are rudimentary at best), and I'm trying to automate the creation of config files. I'm basically trying to take a list of MAC Addresses (which are manually inputted by the user), and create text files with those MAC Addresses as their names, with .cfg appended to the end. I've managed to stumble around and accept the user input and append it into an array, but I've ran into a stumbling block. I'm obviously in the very infant phase of this program, but it's a start. Here's what I've got so far:

```
def main():
     print('Welcome to the Config Tool!')
     macTable = []
     numOfMACs = int(input('How many MAC addresses are we provisioning today? '))
     while len(macTable) < numOfMACs:
     mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: "+".cfg")
     macTable.append(mac)


     open(macTable, 'w')
main()
```

As can be seen, I'm trying to take the array and use it in the open command as the filename, and Python doesn't like it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't `open(macTable, 'r')` because `open` expects a string for the first argument, not a list.  You can `for fname in macTable: open(fname, 'w')`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I can see is the indentation of the while loop. You have:

```
while len(macTable) < numOfMACs:
mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: "+".cfg")
macTable.append(mac)
```

while it should be:

```
while len(macTable) < numOfMACs:
    mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: "+".cfg")
    macTable.append(mac)
```

As for the files, you need to open them in a loop too, so either:

```
for file in macTable:
    open(file, 'w')
```

Or you can do it in the while as well:

```
while len(macTable) < numOfMACs:
    mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: "+".cfg")
    macTable.append(mac)
    open(mac, 'w')
    macTable.append(mac)
```

Another thing you might want to change is the input processing. I understood that you want to read MAC adresses from the user and name the config files `<MAC>.cfg`. Thus I suggest to change

```
mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: "+".cfg")
```

to

```
mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone:")
filename = mac + ".cfg"
```

and then you need to decide if you want to have MAC adresses or the filenames in you `macTable`

Comment: I had the correct indentation in the while loop, The formatting just went kinda screwy and I didn't correct it while pasting it into my question. I did it within the while loop which works nicely! Now onto inserting my config!

Comment: Can someone please inform me why the downvote? Thanks for letting me know how to improve my answers.

Comment: you are not decrementing `numOfMACs` which would result in an infinite `while` loop.

Comment: I tried upvoting your comment, but apparently I don't have enough reputation, and it downvoted it.....I'm not sure why. Your answer worked nicely.

Comment: @anmol_uppal, That's why there is the `len(macTable)` - the macTable is growing.

Comment: @NateHill Not having enough reputation wouldn't downvote it. More likely someone else downvoted it at the same time. But you can mark my answer as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should post it as another question, but I'm trying to input about 21 lines of an XML file, inserting the MAC address in the middle. I've found that I can use a variable for the open command, then use variable.write to write text into the file. The XML file that I'm trying to insert has plenty o' punctuation, and ends up escaping the quotes for the command. Is there a better way for me to do this?

I want to escape the quotes, enter the MAC address, then write the rest of the file.

Comment: @NateHill That definitely sounds like it would deserve a new question or individual research as it's not directly connected to this.

Comment: A new question it will be! Thank you!

Comment: I would really be interested why the downvotes, if anyone can enlighten me about what's wrong with my answer, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open a list. You need something like:

```
open(macTable[index], 'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need a separate list to store the values entered by the user you can create the files on the fly.

```
def main():
    print('Welcome to the Config Tool!')
    #macTable = []
    numOfMACs = int(input('How many MAC addresses are we provisioning today? '))
    while numOfMACs:
        mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: ")
        mac += ".cfg"     # Adding extension to the file name

        with open(mac, 'w') as dummyFile:    # creating a new dummy empty file
            pass

        numOfMACs-=1    #Avoiding the infinite loop
main()
```

However you can simple use a `for` loop to run for specified number of times which mill make your code cleaner:

```
def main():
        print('Welcome to the Config Tool!')
        #macTable = []
        numOfMACs = int(input('How many MAC addresses are we provisioning today? '))
        for i in range(numOfMACs):
            mac = input("Enter the MAC of the phone: ")
            mac += ".cfg"     # Adding extension to the file name

            with open(mac, 'w') as dummyFile:    # creating a new dummy empty file
                pass
    main()
```